# Presenting UIAlertViewController throwing "View not in window heirarchy" - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Firstly, I am not calling this from the `viewDidLoad()` method. It's its own method in the ViewController class that is presenting the Alert.

I build an instance of a UIView. In that view class there is a button that, when pressed, calls the view controller method to display the alert (because apple decided these need to be view controllers).

However, when the method is called, it throws the typical "view not in window hierarchy" warning.

The View Controller:

```
let feedVC: FeedViewController = FeedViewController()

class FeedViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //stuff happens
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        //here is where i build the views and display them
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        let returned = feedMngr.retrieveFeed()

        if (returned) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.constructFeedStack()
                self.view.addSubview(self.firstCardView!)
                self.view.insertSubview(self.secondCardView!, belowSubview: self.firstCardView!)
                self.view.insertSubview(self.thirdCardView!, belowSubview: self.secondCardView!)
                self.view.insertSubview(self.fourthCardView!, belowSubview: self.thirdCardView!)
            }
        }
    }

    func throwFlagAlert() {
        NSLog("throwing flag alert")
        // set up the alert controller here
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Flag Content",
            message: "Do you wish to flag this post as offensive?",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // Cancel action
        //   nil handler means "no action if Cancel button selected"
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
            handler: nil))

        // Confirm action
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Flag",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
 }
```

And the funciton in the UIView that calls this method:

```
func flagContent(sender: UIButton!) {
    //feedVC is the global instance of the view controller
    //it's the only way I could think to access the VC from within the view
    feedVC.throwFlagAlert(feedVC)
}
```

**EDIT: RESOLVED**
So that others who experience this frustration may know:
The answer was to do the following in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
feedVC = self
```

Answer (score 1):

So that others who experience this frustration may know:
The answer was to do the following in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
feedVC = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in dispatch_async block and then try to present alert controller.

This worked for me.